# What does it means 'keelhaul the mizzenmast'?

Tags: meaning

Please explain the meaning of the phrase 'keelhaul the mizzenmast'.
I guess it means to drag someone through the water under the keel of a ship and to begin so it do at the third mast named the mizzenmast. Right?
Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112170/discussion-on-question-by-ivan-what-does-it-means-keelhaul-the-mizzenmast).

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.